# PHP LARAVEL Update with save() doesn't work sometimes

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, eloquent

I have a strange problem. I'm trying to update a database entry with the save function, but the changed columns only update sometimes but most times they do not change yet I don't get any errors.

This is the code in my update function:

```
public function editadvocatedetails(Request $request){
        try {

            ##get original data 
            $oldclaimantdets = Clthirdparties::where('claimant_code',$request->claimant_code)->first();
    

            // ##get new data
            $claimant_dets = Clthirdparties::where('record_type',$oldclaimantdets->record_type)->where('code',$oldclaimantdets->code)->first();
            $claimant_dets->name = $request->name;
            $claimant_dets->record_type = $request->record_type;
            $claimant_dets->claimant_type = $request->claimant_type;
            $claimant_dets->e_mail=$request->e_mail;
            $claimant_dets->id_no=$request->id_no;
            $claimant_dets->pin_number = $request->pin_number;
            $claimant_dets->mobile = $request->mobile;
            // // dd($claimant_dets);
            $claimant_dets->save();
            // dd($claimant_dets);

            
            $mm = $claimant_dets->getChanges();
            
            $user = Auth::user()->user_name;
            $process = 'Update Claimant Details';
            $claimant_code = $request->claimant_code;

            $yy = $this->log_data($mm,$claimant_dets,$user,$process,$claimant_code);

            Session::flash('success,'.$request->name.' details has been updated');
            return redirect()->back();

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            
            Session::flash('error,'.$request->name.' failed to be updated');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
```

My Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clthirdparties extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'oracle';  
        protected $table='clthirdparties';
    public $timestamps=false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    public $primaryKey='claimant_code';
    public $incrementing=false;
        protected $guarded = [];
    
}
```

When I print the values before the save, I get the correct values for both the old and new data.

It looks like the save() doesn't execute. The redirect is executed.

I'm aware of the update() method, but I used this way for updating entries in my database a lot and until now I never had any problems and I don't get where the problem is.

In the meantime I have reverted to update() to run the update query to solve the problem. But I still want to know why it is happening?

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: It may happen if `$claimant_dets = Clthirdparties::where('record_type',$oldclaimantdets->record_type)->where('code',$oldclaimantdets->code)->first();` have no results

Comment: You need to check your query if it gives proper result

Comment: As @LeenaPatel already mentioned, when `$claimant_dets` will  `null`, the `save()`  method wont work. You can use `firstOrFail()` method instead

Comment: When I print the $claimant_dets values before the save, I get the correct values for both the old and new data. I tried firstOrFail() as well and it didn't work.

Comment: i dont think you need to execute the same query 2 times. `$oldclaimantdets` and `$claimant_dets` gives same result. no need to write 2nd query `$claimant_dets` you can perform your update on `$oldclaimantdets`

Comment: When it doesn't execute it presumably throws an excption? What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes hmm..., save() method is formally dependent on $fillable attribute array in the model. So, try defining fillable attributes.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clthirdparties extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'oracle';  
        protected $table='clthirdparties';
    public $timestamps=false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    public $primaryKey='claimant_code';
    public $incrementing=false;
        protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['name','record_type','claimant_type','e_mail','id_no','pin_number','mobile',] ; //include all your attributes here.
    
}
```